# Extract a JSON values from a txt file and write them seperated by comma

Tags: json, bash

I have txt file with curl response with information on the thousands of files downloaded and the year in which they were downloaded.
I try unsuccessfully (sed+grep) to extract the **filename** and the **year** and write them to a separate file ("filname+year.txt") separated by a comma.

```
{"status_code":"200",
    "status_message":"Results found.",
    "results":[{"filename":"test189.pdf",
        "year":"2012",
        "URL":"https:\/\/www.orkistar.org\/random.php?q=iper.pdf&y=2012"
    } 
......
```

Any idea?

Comment: Since JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, it would be relatively easy with Node and JavaScript. How's your JavaScript?

Comment: What is producing that JSON, and why is it escaping the forward slashes in the URL?

Answer (score 4):

Use a JSON aware tool, e.g. `jq`:

```
jq -r '.results[] as $r | $r.filename + "," + $r.year' < file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

jq has a filter for converting to CSV. Using it ensures various edge cases are handled appropriately, assuming the goal is to generate valid CSV:

```
jq -r '.results[] | [.filename, .year] | @csv' file.json
```

In any case, notice that there is no need to introduce any named variables.

Comment: Please don't add tags to the question so that your answer appears to fit better. The OP may have a very good reason not to use (or include) jq. While jq may be the "right" way to handle this, it's not part of the question until the OP puts it there.

Comment: I understand the point, but (a) the OP is a new contributor and did write "Any idea?", and (b) the answer that first mentioned jq and that has the most points is not mine. So I think adding relevant tags is in this case both reasonable and helpful.  Or is it a flaw in SO that there aren't separate tags for Q and A?

Comment: So... (a) A better response to "Any idea?" might be to refer the OP to [point #4 of the off-topic list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Being new doesn't excuse fishing requests, it just makes the responses less pointed. And (b) the point count on someone else's answer should have nothing to do how you govern yourself. A comment for the OP asking "Do you know about `jq`?" would be perfectly reasonable. Changing the question to match your answer is not. As for your question ... that's a great question, and I'd encourage you to ask it on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).